# Cell with no form using NotebookWrite

Tags: notebooks, cells

Is there a way to create a cell with no form? Usually a cell is either an input cell or an output cell, for example if you do `NotebookWrite[InputNotebook, "test"]` and hit Ctrl+E, the cell is in the input form `Cell["test", "Input"]`. However, if you do `CreateDocument["test"]`, there is no form related to the cell, i.e., `Cell["test"]`. 
Is there a way to create a cell with no form using `NotebookWrite[]`?

Comment: Is `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell["test"]]` or `CellPrint[Cell["test"]]` what you are after?

Comment: `NotebookWrite` works in this case, thank you. I am actually trying to manipulate the notebook from a palette, using `CellPrint` always prints the cell in the message box instead of the `InputNotebook[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you evaluate `CreateDocument["test"]` you get a new notebook with a single text cell whose content is "test".

I believe you would get the same result with

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["test"]]
```

The second argument to `NotebookWrite` is the "data" you want to write to `nb`. If you specify that you want a text cell, then that's what you'll get.  As the documentation states, if you provide some data that is not a Cell construct, and one is needed, then it will wrap the data in a Cell construct.

Comment: There is a difference between a `Cell` with no assigned style as the OP wants (for what reason?) and a `"Text"` cell, which you might make clearer in your answer. You can easily see that with `NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["test"]]` vs. `NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["test","Text"]]`. What these two cases look like depends on the active stylesheet, of course...

Comment: @albert-retey: The difference is the style of the text cell.  Both `Cell["test"]` and `Cell["test", "Text"]` are text cells, but the latter has a named style.

Comment: yes, my porposal was that you explain in your answer what exactly it is that you refer to with "text cell". I **guess** you call a "text cell" one that has a string or `TextData` as content as opposed to an expression cell which has `BoxData` as content, which -- as you mentioned -- hasn't anything to do with its style, which can be "Text" or not. It probably also is worth mentioning that some functions (e.g. `CellPrint` and `NotebookWrite`) expect low level `Cell` expression as arguments while others (like `CreateDocument`) accept higher level stuff like `TextCell`...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I wanted this because of the alignment issues actually. The cells generated by `NotebookWrite[]` does not line up with other cells given by `CreateDocument[]`, and when I looked at the cell structure, the only difference is that the cells given by `CreateDocument[]` does not have a style

Answer (score 5):

There are two things that I think need to be distinguished to understand the different behavior of `NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "test"]` and `CreateDocument["test"]`:

## Cell Representation

There are two levels of abstraction for expressions representing cells in Mathematica. The older lower level representation is what `NotebookWrite` and e.g. the notebook option `DockedCells` expect exclusively. That are expressions with head `Cell` which need either a string, a `TextData` or a `BoxData` expression as first argument, the style of the cell as second and as many cell-options as you want after that. If you want the cell to show 2d-formatted content, you have to supply the corresponding boxes wrapped in `BoxData` as the first argument. It seems common to refer to cells which have a string or `TextData` in the first argument as text cells while cells which have a box-formatted expression wrapped in `BoxData` are refered to as expression cells.

There is also a newer form of cell-reperesentation, namely `TextCell` and `ExpressionCell` and they are very similar to `Cell` but make explicit what their content is meant to be and do some automatic conversion of the first argument if and when necessary. It might be of interest that if not just given a string as first argument, `TextCell` still creates an expression cell. Some functions as `CellPrint` and `CreateDocument` will accept these in their arguments (as well as the lower level `Cell`) and at some point they are  automatically converted to the corresponding lower level `Cell` expressions that you see in the frontend when e.g. hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Most functions which accept cells in their input do some automatical conversions to cells when they find just strings, and obviously what `NotebookWrite` does is in that case is different than what `CreateDocument` does. If you want the two to create the same thing, then you should -- as others have suggested -- explicitly tell them what you want and use a specific cell expression instead of just a string.

## Cell Styles

Independent of their content (text cell containing string vs. expression cell containing boxes) there are the cell styles which control how a cell will look and behave. I honestly don't know what exactly the documented behavior is for cells with no style given, so to some extent I think one is asking for some arbitrariness if one creates such cells.  The look and behavior of a cell is controlled by the stylesheet of the notebook in which the cell lives. So by explicitly stating which style the cells you generate should be will make them look alike and e.g. their content should be nicely aligned.

But you can overwrite every setting that affects a cell through its style by explicitly setting options for the corresponding cell. That is what happens if you use the `Cell` or `Format` menus of the frontend to manipulate a selecte cell but can just as well done programmatically. Making use of that you can create cells which will show their content nicely aligned even if they have different (or no) styles defined, e.g.:

```
cellmargins = {{10, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}};
nb = CreateDocument[Cell["line 1", "Section", CellMargins -> cellmargins]];
SelectionMove[nb, After, Notebook];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["line 2", CellMargins -> cellmargins]];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["line 3", "Text", CellMargins -> cellmargins]]
```

the above does set the left cell margins of all cells to 10, which will overwrite the settings for their corresponding style. Of course you could use the same mechanism to make content of cells with the same style not be aligned. You might have noticed the usage of `Inherited` for the other alignment values which will leave those at the style-specific settings. You could even do such an alignment a-posteriori once the content of a notebook has been created in any way. The following will enforce larger left margins in the notebook that just has been generated:

```
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], 
 CellMargins -> {{50, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}]
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `Paste[…]` seems to accomplish the same thing as `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook,…]`, except that `Paste` can handle the higher-level constructs like `EvaluationCell`. When I discovered that, it saved me a *lot* of grief.